# Rock, Paper, Scissors game: entering the correct value returns the wrong console.log message

Tags: javascript

Sometimes when I enter "rock" in the prompt and hit OK, the console will say "Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors" even in case I had actually done that. I believe this is due to the else clause, I'm just not sure what I did wrong.

Also, other times when I enter "rock" in the prompt and hit OK, nothing happens in the console (no score is added). Below is the screenshot[image]

```
const playerSelection = ''
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))

function computerPlay(){
  let values = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
  valueToUse = values [Math.floor(Math.random()* values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  while(true){
    playerSelection = prompt ('Pick your poison');

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock' && computerPlay() === 'paper'){
      computerScore += 1
      console.log('Sorry! Paper beats Rock')
    } 
    else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock'.toLowerCase() && computerPlay() === 'scissors'){
      playerScore += 1
      console.log('Good job! Rock beats Scissors');
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log('Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors')
    }

  console.log (`User Selection: ${playerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Player Score: ${playerScore} 
Computer Selection: ${computerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Computer Score: ${computerScore}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: you haven't handled the case when the computer picks a rock and the player picks a rock, if this happens the else block will trigger

Comment: also you can remove `'rock'.toLowerCase()` and make it just `'rock'`, as the string `'rock'` is already in lowercase

Comment: What's the point of the `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` arguments in `playRound` when you're re-prompting for the user choice and re-rolling the computer choice?

Comment: Looking at the `playerSelection` declaration it seems to be a constant but inside while statement your are changing its value! Should be a variable (var or let)!

Answer (score 1):

You only call `computerSelection` once, at the beginning of pageload:

```
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
```

It then proceeds to only get used in the log:

```
Computer Selection: ${computerSelection.toUpperCase()} |
```

But your tests call `computerPlay` *again*, creating new strings for the computer every time:

```
if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock' && computerPlay() === 'paper'){
  //  function invocation                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  computerScore += 1
  console.log('Sorry! Paper beats Rock')
} 
else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock'.toLowerCase() && computerPlay() === 'scissors'){
  //  function invocation                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In addition to that, you aren't exhaustively testing each possibility for rock-paper-scissors (like when the player picks something other than 'rock').

To start with, call `computerPlay` only once, then use the `computerSelection` variable:

```
if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
  computerScore += 1
  console.log('Sorry! Paper beats Rock')
} else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
```

Also note that there isn't much point calling `toLowerCase` on something that's already a lower-cased string literal - just use the plain string.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the code as following

1. Remove all unnecessary global variable declarations.
2. Remove unnecessary arguments of playRound function.
3. Add more logic for other player selection cases.
4. Nest condition for computer selection cases.

```
playRound();

function computerPlay(){
  let values = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
  valueToUse = values [Math.floor(Math.random()* values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

function playRound() {
  let playerSelection;
  let computerSelection;
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  while(true){
    playerSelection = prompt('Pick your poison').toLowerCase();
    computerSelection = computerPlay();

    if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
        if (computerSelection === 'paper') {
           computerScore += 1;
        } else if (computerSelection === 'scissors') {
           playerScore += 1;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
        if (computerSelection === 'scissors') {
           computerScore += 1;
        } else if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
           playerScore += 1;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {
        if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
           computerScore += 1;
        } else if (computerSelection === 'paper') {
           playerScore += 1;
        }
    } else {
      console.log('Please type Rock, Paper, or Scissors');
      continue;
    }
  console.log (`User Selection: ${playerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Player Score: ${playerScore} 
Computer Selection: ${computerSelection.toUpperCase()} | Computer Score: ${computerScore}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, what does the continue statement do?

Comment: Hi @Parham
Continue statement ignores the rest of commands in the loop block and starts again from the top of block.
In this case, you don't need to show computer/your score when you input wrong string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimalist version of the game as a complete rewrite:

```js
function game(){
 var usr, u, c, g, score=[0,0],last="";
 const words=["rock","paper","scissors"];

 while(usr=prompt(last+"\nScore (you:computer):  "+score.join(":")+"\nYour choice:")) {  
  while((u=words.indexOf(usr.toLowerCase()))<0) usr=prompt("invalid choice, please enter again,\none of: "+words.join(", "));
  
  c=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  g=(3+u-c)%3; // who wins?
  if(g) score[g-1]++;
  last="you: "+words[u]+", computer: "+words[c]+" --> "
  +["draw","you win!!!","you lost - sorry."][g];
 }
}
game()
```